# Apply ngClass for select validation on table rows

Tags: angular

Using Angular, I have created a table with rows that contain 4 dropdowns, each with options 1, 2, 3, and 4. Each option should be selected once per row.

I would like to apply an `ngClass` to each row whose selected options does not equal 10 or does not have each option selected.

How can I do this?

I have created a [StackBlitz for this issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scdcrs).

Comment: You mean a row the sum of the options selected equal to 10,
And
a row which there is no option selected ??

Comment: @bereketgebredingle I meant that each row needs to have each option selected. If this is true, then the sum of the row’s selected options will be 10 so the ‘ngClass’ statement could be either of these.

Comment: Man I cant understand you saying either of these ?

I mean u use 'and' to describe the options.... 

I am trying to help u.

Comment: @bereketgebredingle I'm trying to say that I see two methods to achieve this. Method 1: I can check the sum of the selected options for each row. If it is less than 10, then apply the class. Method 2: If 1, 2, 3, or 4 has not been used once in the row, then apply the class.

Comment: In the method two, u can see that by default 1 is selected. so this make the method two always true.